# Unity: Touch controls during Update function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have create a `PlayerInputHandler` which is added to my main `gameObject` to deal with the user inputs (touch as it is for mobile).
I simply have a character that I can select by touching it on my screen and unselect by touching this character again.

```
public class PlayerInputHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
  void Update()
  {
    if(Input.touchCount > 0){
      Touch pos = GetMouseWorldPositionWithZ(Input.GetTouch(0).position, Camera.main);
      if(checkIfPosCorrespondsToCharacter(pos)) {
        characterSelected != characterSelected;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, ***sometimes***, it selects and unselects my character directly. Would it be because the `update` is called several times during one "`touch event`" ?

Comment: Yep. Create a flag, set it on touch down, reset it on touch up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Update will be triggered several times during one touch on the screen, it needs to have a flag to prevent it being triggered several times in a row.